# validateFunctionArguments:2800: failed assertion `(length - offset)(11088) must be >= 12368 at buffer binding at index 1 for scn_node[0].'

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt, metal, vertex-buffer

not sure what would be the best way to ask this question...
But I have a scene kit scene with skinned human model (which consists of several skinned meshes, some have blend shapes (morphs), bone hierarchy and > 60 different materials). Some meshes have 3-8 materials assigned to them. All those meshes are grouped under 8 groups.

When I run project on device (iPhone 5s, iPad Pro)
I get this error:

> validateFunctionArguments:2800: failed assertion `(length - offset)(11088) must be >= 12368 at buffer binding at index 1 for scn_node[0].'

[image]
If I hide first two groups of meshes, then project runs perfectly fine.
If I unhide first two groups and hide everything else then app also runs ok on devices.
However if I show all 8 groups app crashes and gives that error.
If I remove all materials in 3D package and then export model with single material then everything runs well with all 8 groups shown.

We are using Metal.
Latest Xcode 8, latest iOS 10

What can be causing this? Scene only has that model and nothing else.
Any help or advice greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SceneKit. You should probably [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thank you,I've submitted a bug report to Apple, hope there will be any suggestion as what I can actually do meanwhile...

Comment: Meanwhile, you can try running without the validation and capture layers enabled in your scheme settings. If this is a bug in the validation layer instead of in SceneKit, that should avoid the crash.

Comment: Thank you @warrenm, it works well with validation disabled! :)